# Accepting parameters from a ruby on rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

I am trying to send a field from one form to another form, but I keep receiving a undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

View:

```
<%= form_tag(assets_new_path, method: "submit") do %>
    <%= text_field(:asset, :type, size: 20, class: 'form-control') %>
    <%= submit_tag("+", :class => 'btn btn-default') %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @asset = Asset.new
    @type = params[:asset][:type]
end
```

Note: I have an object defined with the name of Asset (thus the Asset.new).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the two forms, please?

Comment: Shouldn't text_field be text_field_tag? unless you are finding it to a form ala f.text_field?

Comment: There is only one form, so not sure what you mean by two forms. And I never thought about inspecting them before. I'll go do that

Comment: @user3929531 your initial statement in your post, *I am trying to send a field from one form to **another** form*, implies TWO forms.

Comment: Ah whoops. Yes there is a receiving form. I don't have the receiving field coded into the form yet however. I wanted to get the sending form and the controller working first. Could the fact that I haven't coded in the field for the receiving form be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you have to "tell" where that form is so that you can send a parameter and put it as a value in a field. You can either tell us and we can figure out for you or "tell" your application :P

Comment: This problem has since been solved. Thank you everyone for your time.